# UI not updating with Android Timer on every tick

Tags: android, user-interface, timer

I have  a Textview that when it is tapped is meant to start/pause the countdown timer I set up inside it:

```
//Timer functionality
public boolean bTimerRunning = false;
public CountDownTimer timer;
private long currentTime=180000;

 public void onTimerTap(View v) {

    if( bTimerRunning) {
        //stop timer
        timer.cancel();
        bTimerRunning = false;
    }
    else{
        //start timer

        //get textview
        final TextView etTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);

        //setup timer
        timer = new CountDownTimer(currentTime, 1000 ) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                String currentTimeStr = String.format("%d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))
                );

                //save value
                currentTime = millisUntilFinished;

                //show on text
                etTime.setText(currentTimeStr);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {


            }
        };

        timer.start();
        bTimerRunning = true;
    }


}
```

This works without a problem. The issue is that when I hit the volume up/down code, I want it to do the same thing. However, I only updates the timer for one second, then freezes on the UI. How can I make it so that it updates on the UI on each tick?

Here's what I have so far:

```
    //allow volume up/down to
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        //start/stop timer
        TextView etTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);

        //click it
        etTimer.performClick();

        // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
        try{
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            v.vibrate(500);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
    else return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

}
```

Comment: Use a surefaceview if you want the UI to be drawn by timers

Comment: I've never heard of that. Care to point me in the right direction on a tutorial or etc?

Comment: This one looks decent http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame3.html